# Adding missing rows of data in a collection - unexplanable Laravel behavior

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I have a table of data and I need to fetch an array from it, that looks like this:

```
[
   ['Mon', 25],
   ['Tue', 13],
   ['Thu', 25]
]
```

I'm achieving this through some collection acrobatics. At some point I am mapping the collection adding the numerical value of that day (1 Monday, 2 Tuesday) as a key, so I can `sortKeys()` later.

The problem is not all days are always present and I want to add them with a value of 0 at their respective place.

My first attempt was `foreach` on an array of days of the week, and if
`$collection->flatten()->search($day)` returns false, prepend that day. This works fine, but **Thu** always get appended. It never returns true on the search even though it's copied and pasted and should be identical. All other days are skipped/prepended correctly...

Then I tried `array_search` on `toArray()` and the same thing happened. `Thu` never returns true ...

This is extremely weird, basically `Thu == Thu` returns `false`

Is there anyway I can use array_merge or something like that to make it better (or get it working at all?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way of doing it. It could be done much cleaner, if your data was structured different in the first place, like using day name/value as key, instead of having both in sub arrays, but I will keep to the original question:

```
$defaultDays = collect([
    ['Mon', 0],
    ['Tue', 0],
    ['Wed', 0],
    ['Thu', 0],
    ['Fri', 0],
    ['Sat', 0],
    ['Sun', 0],
]);
$days        = [
    ['Mon', 25],
    ['Tue', 13],
    ['Thu', 25]
];

// Use $defaultDays to map, as we will need all seven days no matter what.
$days = $defaultDays->map(static function (array $defaultDay) use ($days) {
    // Current match is the default day...
    $match = $defaultDay;
    foreach ($days as $day) {
        if ($day[0] === $defaultDay[0]) {
            $match = $day;
        }
    }

    return $match;
});
```

This will result in:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1388
  #items: array:7 [
    0 => array:2 [
      0 => "Mon"
      1 => 25
    ]
    1 => array:2 [
      0 => "Tue"
      1 => 13
    ]
    2 => array:2 [
      0 => "Wed"
      1 => 0
    ]
    3 => array:2 [
      0 => "Thu"
      1 => 25
    ]
    4 => array:2 [
      0 => "Fri"
      1 => 0
    ]
    5 => array:2 [
      0 => "Sat"
      1 => 0
    ]
    6 => array:2 [
      0 => "Sun"
      1 => 0
    ]
  ]
}
```